# Wait for async to finish with DispatchSemaphore

Tags: swift, alamofire

From the beneath code, I would have hoped for printing "1" and not "0" while implementing the semaphore with alamofire. Do you know why?

```
public func mySync() -> NSNumber{

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["":""]
    let parameters: Parameters = ["":""]

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

    var aNumber: NSNumber = 0

    Alamofire.request(
        "http://localhost:8000/users.json",
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: URLEncoding.default,
        headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            aNumber = 1
            semaphore.signal()
    }

    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
    return aNumber
}

print(mySync())

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Your code initially was `DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)` which looks correct. Now you have changed it to `DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)` and then `semaphore.wait()` returns immediately.

Comment: *Wait for async to finish with DispatchSemaphore* is very bad. Face the asynchronous pattern and write a completion handler.

Comment: Prints `1` here. Even with `DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)`:-/

Comment: Strange, thank you for verifying - hmm